# Why my theme is not showing on the admin panel on Magento 2.1?

Tags: theme, admin-panel, magento2.1.6

I have created a new custom theme in it. My theme structure is as follows.

```
app\design\frontend\Magento\mytheme
----css
----js
----images
----fonts
----etc
----media
----Magento_Theme
----composer.json
----theme.xml
----requirejs-config.js
----registeration.php

In etc folder
--------view.xml

In media folder
--------preview image
```

The issue is that my theme is not showing in the admin panel. I need to apply it.

I have also run setup upgrade and content deployed command but that not effect.

Can any one suggest me any solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the file `registeration.php` is wrong, change to:

```
registration.php
```

> Remember to check the content of all files if it doesn't work. You can copy and paste the essentials files of the Luma theme and change the name of the theme to your.

Comment: ooopppss. crap. Thanks Rafael. That fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use different name instead of **Magento**. Like below

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/mytheme
```

Example: http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-theme-create-sample-custome-theme/

Comment: not worked. Still not loaded in admin panel